# What is the "Google Drive Client Native Proxy" Chrome Extension for?

Tags: google-drive, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I noticed I have an extension installed, "Google Drive Client Native Proxy", but I'm not familiar with what its purpose is, nor do I remember installing it. I'm assuming it was installed by Google for some (hopefully) good reason. Can anyone elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[#10](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=396098) has:

> A very simple chrome extension that proxies a chrome Port established with a client JS -- that is, JS running on a vanilla web page with permission to connect to the present chrome extension -- to a chrome native messaging host -- that is the chromello executable. This is necessary because the chrome security model does not allow untrusted JS to speak directly to a native messaging host.

Also (#15): “it's a legitimate extension, they pulled it from their latest update and will look for a better way of doing this before pushing it again from what I understand.” and (#17) (ie may go away of its own accord).

Comment: Any idea what repercussions I'll see if I disable it?  I can relate with the last (#21) commenter on the Chromium Issue: `I was browsing through my chrome extensions and spotted "Google Drive Client Native Proxy" - everything about the entry strikes me as suspicious and a security risk. There are no details whatsoever about this extension, and I had absolutely no notification of it being installed.`